# Bootstrap table cell padding issue with chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am having a hard time trying to figure out what the hell is going on with chrome.

1. I opened the same file with chrome and firefox, and while I have no problem with Firefox, Chrome adds these weird paddings on top and bottom of table cells even though I forced it to be 0.
2. Other weird thing, I can 'fix it' (pretty ugly but much better) in Chrome by removing the paddings in the buttons, but this ruins Mozilla's.

   [chrome issue shown in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiZ8i.png)

EDIT: fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14845/

```
.keyboard button{
width: 100%;}
```

I found the solution making the fiddle, it was just the height: 100%... For my personnal knowledge, can someone explain this ?

Comment: try to use box-sizing:border-box or else create fiddle so we can help you.

Comment: Bootstrap already adds box-sizing:border-box. I'm trying to reproduce it in a fiddle

Comment: Yes, a [fiddle ](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be very nice. But as far as I remember Chrome shows this "padding" when a cell has empty space and he doesn't know what to do with that. By empty space I mean something setting its height, or something like that.

Comment: Aah, I think you have to give cellpadding=0 and cellspacing=0 in your table tag

Comment: "The cellpadding attribute of <table> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead." from W3school